# Unable to submit form in javascript after sweet alert has been closed

Tags: javascript, html, sweetalert2

I have created an application that will feature a demo login. The Demo login will have a sweet alert pop up to let the user know that the changes they make will not be saved to the database. The problem is that the form doesn't submit after the user presses ok button that will close the sweet alert. What is the proper syntax to submit the form after the ok button has been pressed?

Below is my `html`:

```
  <form method="post" id="submitForm" name="demoSubmitForm">
    <div class="demo-button pt-3">
      <button type="button" name="demoEmail" value="DemoEmail" class="au-btn au-btn--block au-btn--blue 
        m-b-20" onclick="ShowSweetAlert()">
        Demo Application
      </button>
    </div>
  </form>
```

---

Below is my script:

```
function ShowSweetAlert() {
    Swal.fire({
        icon: 'warning',
        title: 'You are logging in as a Demo User!',
        text: 'Changes you make to the Application will not be saved once you log out.',
        onClose: document.getElementById('submitForm').submit()     /*document.demoSubmitForm.submit()*/
    });
}
```

At the moment neither do `document.demoSubmitForm.submit()` nor `document.getElementById('submitForm').submit()` work in order to submit the form.

[Video of the Problem](https://www.dropbox.com/s/zvhqk7hqr6s6ids/Rolodex.gif?dl=0)

Answer (score 0):

Add this `Script`:

```
$('#submitForm').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var form = $(this).parents('form');
  swal({
    title: "Are you sure?",
    text: "You will not be able to recover this imaginary file!",
    type: "warning",
    showCancelButton: true,
    confirmButtonColor: "#DD6B55",
    confirmButtonText: "Yes, delete it!",
    closeOnConfirm: false
  }, function(isConfirm) {
    if (isConfirm) form.submit();
  });
});
```